# Thread 5: Simultaneous accesses to 0x10b883638, but modification requires exclusive access

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayeritem

I had asked [this question regarding some Apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56470171/why-does-observer-for-status-change-of-avasset-not-work/56580374#56580374) code and making it work.

I have [looked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415901/simultaneous-accesses-to-0x1c0a7f0f8-but-modification-requires-exclusive-access) but the answer there does not solve my problem
Although I solved that problem I am not getting the bellow error on the line shown.

> Thread 5: Simultaneous accesses to 0x10b883638, but modification requires exclusive access

```
    private var playerItemContext = 0

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    // Only handle observations for the playerItemContext
    print("jdslfhjkfdhaldfahjkflhajfldashkjfdshkjlas")
    guard context == &playerItemContext else {
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object,change: change, context: context)
        return
    }
    ...
```

**Why is this and how can I fix this?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simultaneous accesses to 0x1c0a7f0f8, but modification requires exclusive access error on Xcode 9 beta 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415901/simultaneous-accesses-to-0x1c0a7f0f8-but-modification-requires-exclusive-access)

Comment: I have looked at that question and teh answer is old and does not fix my problem @Xcoder

Comment: Did you try this specific answer on that question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47438532/243192

Comment: Yes, it did not change anything for me. @wvteijlingen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    // Only handle observations for the playerItemContext
    guard context == &P2SheetViewController.playerStatusContext else {
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
        return
    }

    if keyPath == #keyPath(AVPlayer.status) {
        let status: AVPlayer.Status
        if let statusNumber = change?[.newKey] as? NSNumber {
            status = AVPlayer.Status(rawValue: statusNumber.intValue)!
        } else {
            status = .unknown
        }

        //Switch over status value
        switch status {
        case .readyToPlay:

            break
        // Player item is ready to play
        case .failed:
            print(".UKNOWN")

            break
        // Player item failed. See error.
        case .unknown:
            print(".UKNOWN")

            break
        // Player item is not yet ready.
        @unknown default: //new jul 17
            print(".UKNOWN")

            break
        }

    }
}
```

Hope it helps